# Read and write JSON data from form to file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I am trying to work with JSON data in Rails.

We need to save some countries in our JSON file which we support. We have created a form which a user can create a new country/state/pincode pair and this form will append the pair in the JSON file. After that, we need to read that JSON file and print which countries are supported.

We know how to read data from the JSON file, but we are having some issues while writing the data in the proper format.

This is the code for reading the data:

```
@data=JSON.parse( IO.read("public/dealer.json") )
```

How can I write data to a file from the form in JSON format?

Answer (score 2):

Given a ruby object, you can generate a file with text in json format like so:

```
require 'json'

data = { "foo" => "bar" }

File.open("output.json", "w+") do |f| 
  f.write(JSON.generate(data))
end
```

Comment: Using above method, in following format JSON file is generated.{"foo":"bar"}. This format causing errors in Reading file data.I want to save data of form  in same file on each submit request in  [{"foo":"bar"},{"first":"name"}]. How it is possible?

Comment: The method I described works fine for me in ruby 1.9.3 and ruby 2.1. What version of ruby are you using? What is the "error" you're receiving?

Comment: I am using rails 4.1.7 and ruby 2.1.4 .I am getting unexpected token error.

Comment: Ok, so that probably means that `JSON` can't directly generate the json format from your data... so what is the `data`?

Comment: I am getting {"name":"Dealer1","country":"select Country","state":"select State","city":"select City","address":"Address"}{"name":"Dealer2","country":"India","state":"Haryana","city":"Panchkula","address":"Address"}{"name":"Dealer3","country":"India","state":"Punjab","city":"Mohali","address":"Address"}

Answer (score 0):

require 'json'

data = [{ "foo" => "bar" } , { "foo1" => "bar1" }]

File.open("output.json", "w+") do |f| 
  f.write(JSON.generate(data))
end

Try this...!